# Can't return value from method containing class which extends AsyncTask

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am trying to return a boolean from my method `checkInvited()`. This method contains a class which extends `AsyncTask<Void,Void,String>`. This is the full method

```
public boolean checkInvited(String player_id){

    final String g_id = game_id;
    final String fr_id = player_id;

    class CheckInvited extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>{
        boolean invited;
        ProgressDialog loading;
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute(){
            super.onPreExecute();
            loading = ProgressDialog.show(InviteFriends.this,"Checking Invite Status","Please Wait...",false,false);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s){
            super.onPostExecute(s);
            loading.dismiss();
            JSON_STRING = s;
            if (s.trim().equals("0")){
                invited = false;
            } else {
                invited = true;
            }

        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... params){

            HashMap<String, String> hashMap = new HashMap<>();
            hashMap.put(Config.KEY_INVITES_GAME_ID, g_id);
            hashMap.put(Config.KEY_INVITES_PLAYER_ID, fr_id);

            RequestHandler rh = new RequestHandler();
            String s = rh.sendPostRequest(Config.URL_CHECK_INVITED, hashMap);
            return s;
        }
    }
    CheckInvited ci = new CheckInvited();
    ci.execute();
    return ci.invited;
}
```

This method calls a predefined method of `sendPostRequest()` which contacts the mySql database through php. My problem is getting the `checkInvited()` method to return true or false. Currently it will only return false when I know at least one of the results should be true.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: The definition of AsyncTask is that it runs asynchronously. You are returning false before the AsyncTask has even finished (maybe even started) executing

Comment: please don't define class inside a method...

Answer (score 0):

It only returns false because async task runs in a seperate thread and might take long to execute depending on carious factors. You are returning value even before async task completes.

I would suggest calling a method which requires the true or false from onPostexecute, as onPostExecute runs after doInBackground completes.